# Un getElementById puede ser utilizado en caso de existir varias veces pero con un diferenciador?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero saber si es posible utilizar el Id de un elemento en caso de ser usado

Por ejemplo tenemos

```
<img id="image1" onclick="usarImagen();" class="img-responsive center-block" src="images\imagen1.jpg" alt="banner1" align="middle"/>
<img id="image2" onclick="usarImagen();" class="img-responsive center-block" src="images\imagen2.jpg" alt="banner2" align="middle"/>
<img id="image3" onclick="usarImagen();" class="img-responsive center-block" src="images\imagen3.jpg" alt="banner3" align="middle"/>
```

y que puedan ser llamados de esta manera:

```
...

function usarImagen() {
        var image = document.getElementById("image*").value;
...
```

en vez de especificar de uno en uno y que se tome únicamente el que sea utilizado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza el método `document.querySelectorAll()` para obtener un arreglo con todos los elementos que coincidan con el selector especificado:

```
var imagenes = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='image' i]");
console.log(imagenes.length); // 3 images
```

El selector es `[id*='image']` donde `id*=` busca una concidencia parcial de la cadena `image`, puede ser al principio, en medio o al final.

Comment: Documentación sobre `querySelectorAll`: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll. Nótese que el método no es exclusivo de `document`, sino que puede hacer selecciones en partes del árbol DOM.

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla de hacerlo es utilizando jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
  var images = $('img[id^="image"]');
  var resultado = '';
  images.each(function(i) { resultado += 'Imagen ' + images[i].id + '\n'; });
  $('#resultado').text(resultado);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image1" onclick="usarImagen();" class="img-responsive center-block" src="images\imagen1.jpg" alt="banner1" align="middle"/>
<img id="image2" onclick="usarImagen();" class="img-responsive center-block" src="images\imagen2.jpg" alt="banner2" align="middle"/>
<img id="image3" onclick="usarImagen();" class="img-responsive center-block" src="images\imagen3.jpg" alt="banner3" align="middle"/>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```